# Text file write not reflecting changes unless file.Close()

Tags: c#, logging, file-io

I am writing a log of my application in to text file using file IO operations. As soon as user launches the application i am logging the details (like who launched, datetime, machine name etc). I am bit worried now becasue the text written to file is not reflected unless it encounters file.Close(). If i use file.Close() method, i cannot further write log to file again because it says 'Cannot write to closed TextWriter'

Is there any way to handle this scenario. I know that logutil meets my requirement, but unfortunatly i cannot use it.

Comment: @downvoter: please downvote with valid comments, simply downvoting doesn't make sence

Comment: What is the type of `file` variable?

Comment: btw its not me downvoting

Comment: We can help you if you provide a fragment of code that fails

Comment: It is almost impossible to make any assumptions without seeing your code.

Comment: of type 'StreamWriter', if required i can provide code snippet.

Comment: Aside from using `flush`, you may be better off using already existing logging tools such as `log4net` and others.

Comment: Its downvote because you have not showed code what are you trying and how?though i am not the one who has downvoted

Comment: @Sayse: I am not suppose to any third party tool(logutil/log4net) in my application (same is mentioned in question)

Answer (score 5):

You need to call Flush periodically to ensure the contents of in-memory buffers are flushed to the file system.

See the [TextWriter.Flush Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Note that flushing here will most likely just dump the contents of any buffers the TextWriter or file has, into a separate type of buffer that the operating system has, so if the power goes out, you're still not guaranteed that the contents was saved. However, other programs would be able to see the contents of the file because the operating system would give them the content, even though it may not physically be on the disk yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `file.Flush()`. It can be called any time you need to clear the buffer, and the stream will remain open:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx

**edit:**

To not lock the file you should close the file after writing a line or use something like this:

```
File.AppendAllText("log.txt", "log entry" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Yes, as soon as i write i am using flush method, but i cant open the file, it throws an error "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". But after file.Close() is executed, i am able to see my file contents. below is the code  if (file != null) file.WriteLine(message); file.Flush();

Comment: also, i tried file.AutoFlush = true. but didn't work

Comment: then try File.AppendAllText

Comment: @Chethan that can be partly controlled by the `FileShare.Read` value (passed to `File.Open`)

Comment: @Shadowshine: this worked for me File.AppendAllText. Thanks